# Web service task throwing an error on 2015 data tools

Tags: sql-server, ssis, wsdl, etl, sql-server-data-tools

I am trying to run a simple web service task and successfully downloaded wsdl file and configured for run. Although it is the only task in the package.

**Error :**

> [Web Service Task] Error: An error occurred with the following error
>   message:
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebserviceTaskException:
>   Could not execute the Web method.
>   The error is: Could not load file or assembly
>    Microsoft.SqlServer.WebServiceTask, Version=14.100.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91 or one of its
>   dependencies.
>   The system cannot find the file specified..  at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebServiceTaskUtil.Invoke(DTSWebMethodInfo
>   methodInfo, String serviceName, Object connection, VariableDispenser
>   taskVariableDispenser) at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebServiceTask.executeThread().

Please help to resolve it... Thanks in advance!!!

**Installation order**

SQL Server 2016

Data Tools 2015 shell

Visual Studio 2017 community

Do i need 2015 visual studio to run 2015 data tools ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look like the error are thrown because the package are using sql server 2017 assemblies which is not installed. (`Microsoft.SqlServer.WebServiceTask, Version=14.100.0.0,`)

This maybe caused during upgrade procedure.

Try changing the deployment target to sql server 2016.

Read more in this article:

- https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4253/backwards-compatibility-in-sql-server-data-tools-for-integration-services/

Also check this link:

- [Could not load file or assembly error in SSIS Web Service Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43848430/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-error-in-ssis-web-service-task)

Comment: Getting this error during execution not while deploying. I have noticed few things in troubleshooting it.

1. Location of Task : C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Tasks\Microsoft.SqlServer.WebserviceTask.dll (Version = 13.0.1601.5)
2. I have installed SQL Server 2015 Data tools then why it is still showing old version rather than 14.100.0.0

Please correct me if I missed anything. Thanks..

Comment: Just try backward compatibility :)

Comment: Awesome...Just tried your recent link and task is working perfectly fine now. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: If it solved your issue you have to accept this answer and if you find it helpful u can upvote